# Empty Parameter an MessagerBox

Tags: debugging, immunity-debugger

I am trying to learn to reverse Engineering , i am very new and my English is very Poor... .I wanting to make this [exercise](http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/archives/2390/2390.htm) , but can't it , because not receive the hWnd identified from the MessageBox ,it is empty ....

The screenshot from they
[image]

My screenshot
[image]

I have to want to make this exercise with Ollydbg and Immunty Debugger , but without result... .I working with a Windows 7 , inside a VirtualBox   .
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#window_handle) Speak what HWND do , what i don't Understande because all crackme.exe which i Downloaded have this parameter [NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx).
Can Please anybody help me and with easy Words explain me how to solve this Problem , Thanks!

Comment: Do you conclude the `HWND` handle to be 0 just from Immunity not showing its value at the call site? Judging from the code this is inside a window proc and I do not see a way for the passed `HWND` handle to be NULL there, `GetDlgItemTextA` would fail in that case anyway. Have you checked `[ebp+8]` manually?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! , i am veryyy new with debugging.... , i have to thought that are a NULL , because HWND have neither value....  i am not a student from IT , can you please tell me , how does to check [ebp+8] manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a hWnd to a MessageBox can be NULL

if you give NULL as an arg it measns the MessageBox is NonModal

NonModal means you can keep working with the parent application without having to dismiss the MessageBox

which version of ollydbg are you using if it was v 1.0  it came with a default commandline plugin  (alt + f1)  where you can type [ebp+8]  and get the result

[image]

if you are using v 2.0 use ctrl+g on the respective panes

if you want to view in dump select dump pane first and then 
hit ctrl+g  type in [ebp+8] and follow expression

or you can use the address relative to option in stack to have a visual

[image]

do not use the executable from octopuslabs it is probably trojanned 
the exe from crackmes.cf appears to be 1 kb less than that of octopuslabs exe

anyway at [ebp+8] you wont get the same handle as in the tutorial it will be different for each invocation
just because you have a different handle does not matter

```
C:\lafarge2>ls -R
.:
crackme.exe  octo

./octo:
filehash.py  getoctocrackme.bat

C:\lafarge2>cat octo\getoctocrackme.bat
wget -c hxxp://BEWARE_MALWARE_octopuslabs.io/legend/files/tuts/R4ndom_tutorial_22.zip
C:\lafarge2>cd octo
C:\lafarge2\octo>getoctocrackme.bat

Length: 1555447 (1.5M) [application/zip]
Saving to: 'R4ndom_tutorial_22.zip'

C:\lafarge2\octo>e:\7z\7z.exe e R4ndom_tutorial_22.zip

Everything is Ok
Files: 7

C:\lafarge2>fc crackme.exe octo\crackme.exe
Comparing files crackme.exe and OCTO\CRACKME.EXE
000000CE: 04 05

0000095F: 79 C9
^C
C:\lafarge2>octo\filehash.py crackme.exe
2ef9a7504dddb18f0ecd7fce3a720dc131c6994d

C:\lafarge2>octo\filehash.py octo\crackme.exe
cdcf6fbbb70010f1c9d4e4b4d2f0dea60f61c50d
```

an extra section

```
C:\lafarge2>dumpbin /nologo octo\crackme.exe | tail -n 5 & dumpbin /nologo crackme.exe | tail -n 5
        8000 .data
        1000 .r4nd
        1000 .rdata
        B000 .rsrc
        4000 .text

        8000 .data
        1000 .rdata
        B000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
```

Comment: Veryyyyyyy Thanks! , my Ollydbg version is  v 1.0 , i had to doing as you tell , command line + (Alt+F1) , it is  7EFDE000 .Can you please help me forward ....

Comment: Why can not receive identical Window as the exercise ??

Comment: i don't know what exercise the link you posted is to a tutorial and appears to have some trojan (hideme) trying to infect  the visitor   post relevent parts to what you did and where you are stuck

Comment: I will to do all exercise from the page ,I have to download the program from here http://crackmes.cf/users/lafarge/lafarges_crackme_2/ , for me who not to have a clue , this exercise is gut , because it speak every step.....

Comment: what is your opinion what i should to do??

Comment: The window handle is just a number assigned when the window is created, it's most likely different for each run, too.

Comment: My Question at the Master , what should i to do for learn Code Cave because i can not does this exercise ...

Comment: @blabb  can you please tell me , how can i to see the trojan ...thanks

Comment: you can compare with fc anyway i added details to the answer

Comment: you mean because a new extra section is , the troyan is to the new section .... , i know what you to speak.... https://haiderm.com/fully-undetectable-backdooring-pe-file/#Adding_a_new_Section_header_method  Thanks

Comment: The crackme.exe wich i working come from  crackmes.cf .... . I will learn more about Assembly ... , now I am here , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm later i will learn Code Cave here , https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20240/The-Beginners-Guide-to-Codecaves .... you speak very gut , you can working as Teacher....

Comment: @ blabb Can you please give me a Tutorial for Reverse Eengineering but easy Understand for beginnen as me ..., thanks